# Music does not start in spotify under ubuntu 10.04

Tags: wine, winetricks, spotify

I am running Spotify 0.8.5 under wine 1.2.2 in ubuntu 10.04.

It was possible to install the spotify application via wine and start the application.
I can log into it via Facebook (I have to use the free version, so the native linux spotify versions can not be used).

I start spotify but when I try to start a song, nothing happens. the time-slider stays at 00:00. Sometimes a song starts for about 17 seconds and I can here the music but then it stops again.

Have you experience with spotify under ubuntu via wine and can help me to play my songs?

Your welcome,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If no Music is playing but Spotify starts without crashes:**

1. Choose Wine > Wine configuration > Audio
2. Select the ALSA Driver (for my machine) and choose Emulation on Hardware Acceleration
3. Make the default sample rate 44100
4. Make the default bits per sample 16
5. Start Spotify via Wine

[Information Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1610170.html)

**Sometimes I have the problem that Spotify crashed on startup, this can be fixed this way:**

1. Install Winetricks via `sudo apt-get install winetricks`
2. Install winhttp via Winetricks (MS winhttp.dll , requires Windows license, but does not check for one)
3. Use DLL Overrides for *winhttp* in wine configuration (`winecfg`)
4. Start Spotify via Wine

[Configure Wine](http://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/config-wine-main)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run it over wine as there is a version of Spotify for Linux.
The guide for doing this is [here](http://www.spotify.com/uk/download/previews/). Let me know how this goes :)

Comment: would be nice yes but.. "(I have to use the free version, so the native linux spotify versions can not be used)"

Comment: Sorry overlooked that fact. :)

Comment: It seems that Spotify for Linux no longer requires a premium account http://www.webupd8.org/2011/12/how-to-install-native-spotify-linux.html